# Create unique SharePoint List B with count of occurences from Sharepoint List A

Tags: power-automate, count

I have a SharePoint list A, that lists all the report rows with 1 column set as a report reference code.

For example:

Row 1 refers to report#01 row 1, Report reference column "Report #01"

Row 2 refers to report#02 row 1, Report reference column "Report #02"

Row 3 refers to report#03 row 2, Report reference column "Report #03"

I have been trying to count the "Report reference column" into a separate summary SharePoint list B, such that, All unique values in "Report reference column" is listed and "count of occurence from Sharepoint List A.

```
Report#01 Count 1
Report#02 Count 2
```

Can anyone help, please?